# Value of type error in C++ function always NULL

Tags: c++, function, void, strdup

i have to do my function always.I can not using standart library.

My_cpy , my_len and my_strdup function in here. Please check it for me. I think it is easy but i have a problem about this function. I showed the error at the end of the page. I think it is clear. In addition this is C++

Thanks a lot.

Codes:

```
void my_cpy(char* dest, const char* src) {

    int i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0') {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
}

int my_len(const char* p) {

    int c = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        c++;
        *p++;
    }
    return c;
}

char *my_strdup(const char *s) {
    char* d = malloc(my_len(s) + 1);    // Space for length + null
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;         //No memory
    my_cpy(d, s);                       // Copy the characters
    return d;                           // Return the new string
}
```

I have error on this functions. How can i solve this problem?

> Error (active)        a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize
>   an entity of type "char *"
>
> ```
> `Error    C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'`
> ```

**I wrote it:**

```
char* d = (char*) malloc(my_len(s) + 1)
```

**but now problem on p . Always NULL.**

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: This is C++ . Maybe later i will use in C

Comment: @UgurBaki This may be C++ in terms of syntax, but it certainly is not C++ in terms of style.  Why are you trying to mimic a function such as `strdup`?  What's wrong with `std::string`, or if you want to learn something, creating your own string class?

Comment: Yes it is rule for me. I wrote with bold . But now problem on `p` . How can i solve this NULL problem? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer below about p.

Comment: It might be an option for you to write this code into a C file and compile with C compiler.  Technically it is undefined behaviour in C++ to malloc and then write chars into the malloc'd space without using `new`.

Comment: Please don't vandalise posts.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` is returning `void *` type. In C it does not need to be cast, but in C++ it needs to be cast explicitly:

```
char* d = static_cast<char*>(malloc(my_len(s) + 1));
```

(prefer `static_cast` to a C-style cast)

You can also use

```
char* d = new[my_len(s) + 1];
```

But in that case you need to make sure that the client of the function will not call `free()` but `delete[]`.

Comment: static_cast is the same as C cast.

Comment: No it isn't, @nikau. A C-style cast is a lot more powerful than a static_cast.

Comment: Yeah ok, what I said is, in this case, that's the same.

Comment: @nikau: Well yes, but prefer `static_cast` because if you make a mistake (like trying to cast away const-ness, or casting between unrelated types), you are more likely to get a compiler error.